# Angular2 IndexOf Finding and Deleting Array Value

Tags: html, arrays, list, angular, ngfor

Hello I'm attempting delete a certain index in my array while using Angular2 and Typescript. I would like to retrieve the index from the value.

My array is declared normally...

```
 RightList = [
    'Fourth property',
    'Fifth property',
   'Sixth property',
]
```

I start out with a basic premise to set up my remove function.

```
       removeSel(llist: ListComponent, rlist:ListComponent){
      this.selectedllist = llist;
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.selectedllist)); // what is to be searched turned into a string so that it may actually be used
```

My console.log of my JSON.Stringify tells me that the value that I will attempt to remove is "Sixth property". However when I attempt to look for this value in my array using the following code. It returns -1 which means my value is not found in the array.

```
  var rightDel = this.RightList.indexOf((JSON.stringify(this.selectedllist)));  // -1 is not found 1 = found
      console.log(rightDel);
```

On my output to the console it does return the item that is to be searched for but does not find the item in the array

```
CONSOLE OUTPUT:
  "Sixth property" // Item to be searched for
 -1   // not found
```

Is there something wrong in my implementation of my function that searches the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course indexOf will not find you item in array because

```
JSON.stringify(this.selectedllist) !== this.selectedllist
```

This is because JSON stringified string encodes quotes around literal, that original string doesn't have. It is easy to test:

```js
var a = 'test';
console.log( JSON.stringify(a), a, JSON.stringify(a) === a )
```

Remove `JSON.stringify` and it should work. In general, to cast something to String type you should use its `.toString()` method, or simply wrap this something into `String(something)`.